# Program ended with exit code: 87

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

My iphone app is crashing with this in the debug window:

> Program ended with exit code: 87

Does anyone know what this exit code refers too. Google isn't helping much.

UPDATE: I have found that this was being caused when I was trying to call

```
[mutArray objectForIndex:indexpath.row]
```

and the index was outside the range of the array.

The stacktrace didn't include anything else besides the code 87 message. Also the console window didn't even slide up when the app crashed. Not very useful I guess. Anyone know how to make it more useful in these situations?

Comment: isn't there anything else in the debug window?

Comment: Best I could find was "87 = Parameter is incorrect".

Comment: What 3rd party libraries are you using? I don't think error code 87 is coming from the iOS SDK.

Comment: Are you getting a stack trace?

Comment: Found the issue, see my update above.

Comment: @ChristianSchlensker You should post as an answer, not as an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Anyone know how to make it more useful in these situations?"*

First, use CMD-SHIFT-R in XCode to show the console window.  You should have seen an error message about accessing an array with an out of bounds index.

Also, use CMD-Y to build & debug (vice CMD-R to build & run) your app.  If it crashes, you will be in the debugger (CMD-SHIFT-Y for debug window) with the exact line of code that crashes, as well as a stack trace, all your variables, etc.